# How work with nested field and list array

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I wrote a small script that checks a field in the MongoDB collection that is duplicated and displays its value and the number of duplicates. And it works fine with fields without a dot, i.e. not with nested fields. But as soon as a nested field appears in the input data, I cannot get its value. I get 'null'.
I see where the problem is. It is in the aggregation data processing cycle. The aggregation itself gives the correct data.

Here is a piece of code:

```
     n=0
     arc = []
     for doc in result:
             if doc["count"] > 1:
                 n=1
                 if "." in args.field:
                     arc.append({args.field: doc.get(f'"{args.field}"'), "count": doc["count"]})
                 else:
                     arc.append({args.field: doc.get(args.field), "count": doc["count"]})
```

This is after trying several options to solve the problem. Initially it was like this:

```
     n=0
     arc = []
     for doc in result:
             if doc["count"] > 1:
                 n=1
                 arc.append({args.field: doc[args.field]), "count": doc["count"]})
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an array of `dict` in python? ... where the `dict` has a `dict`?  Or are you trying to create some JSON in python?

Comment: Dict. I also translate the result of aggregation into a dict: result = list(collection.aggregate(pipeline)) Later I transfer it to JSON. Ultimately, JSON is needed

Comment: Perhaps if you edit your question and show a portion of `result` (a few representatives of `doc`) and your desired ultimate JSON, a reader here could create an aggregation pipeline and/or python code to produce it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem. In my aggregation in Mongo I simple changed field name on name "value" and that's all.